# On unions of independent events

Tags: probability-theory

If the events $\{ E_{\alpha}, \alpha\in A\}$ are independent, then so are the events $\{F_\alpha,\alpha\in A\}$, where each $F_\alpha$ may be $E_\alpha$ or $E_\alpha^c$; also if $\{A_\beta, \beta\in B \}$, where $B$ is an arbitrary index set, is a collection of disjoint countable subsets of $A$, then the events

$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in A_{\beta}}E_\alpha, \quad \beta\in B,$$

are independent.

Presumably if these were finite unions then independence should be easy to show I'm guessing. But here based on the notation these seem to be possibly uncountable unions.

Comment: It might be helpful to pose a question so that others may accurately answer what it is that you are having difficulty with. It is generally frowned upon to simply state a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set of events $\mathcal A$ is independent iff for any *finite* set $\{A_i\in\mathcal A:i=1\dots n\}$ we have $\mathbb P\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(A_i)$.

For unions We can say that if $\mathcal A$ are independent then $\mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 1-\prod_{i=1}^n(1- \mathbb P(A_i))$.

So we can assume $B$ is finite, which helps.

Set $$F_\beta = \bigcup_{\alpha\in A_\beta} E_\alpha$$

Any event with probability one or 0 is independent of everything
so we can assume without loss of generality that $\mathbb P\left(F_\beta\right)<1$.  By the second Borel-Cantelli lemma we must have $\sum_{\alpha\in A_\beta}\mathbb P (E_\alpha) <\infty$.

So choose some $\varepsilon>0$ and for every $\beta\in B$ let $A^\varepsilon_\beta\subset A_\beta$ be a finite set of events such that 
$$\sum_{\alpha\in A_\beta}\mathbb P (E_\alpha) \leq\varepsilon + \sum_{\alpha\in A_\beta^\varepsilon}\mathbb P (E_\alpha).$$

Now the events $$F^\varepsilon_\beta = \bigcup_{\alpha\in A_\beta^\varepsilon} E_\alpha$$ are independent by messing about with finite products. We can arrange things so that $F^\varepsilon_\beta \subset F^\delta_\beta$ whenever $\delta >\varepsilon$ then we have

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{\beta\in B} F_\beta\right) &= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} 
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{\beta\in B} F_\beta^\varepsilon \right) \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \prod_{\beta\in B} \mathbb P(F^\varepsilon_\beta) \\
& =  \prod_{\beta\in B} \mathbb P(F^\beta) \end{array}$$

Then as $B$ is an arbitrary finite subset we are done.